# Populate Numbers Pop-up Menu cell using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, iwork, apple-numbers

I have a Numbers (iWork 09) spreadsheet where I want to be able to populate a Pop-up Menu cell with values to enable easy analysis of selected data.

I have the AppleScript to generate the values that I want put into the Pop-up Menu, but need a means of interacting with the Pop-up Menu's list of values.

Is it possible to use AppleScript to dynamically populate a Pop-up Menu cell?

If so, what is the code to populate the Pop-up Menu with options dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Applescript just automates what the application can already do on its own. So my question to you would be... can you populate that menu in Numbers? Of course Numbers populates the menu, but does Numbers give you the ability to determine what that menu holds. If not then there's no chance you can do it with applescript.

But you really don't need it. If you're running an applescript to generate the values then just popup a choose-from-list dialog box so you can choose the one you want to insert. Then after you choose one use applescript to insert the value into the currently selected cell in Numbers.